# Facebook jQuery Search Script

Tags: jquery

I was following [this tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html), but for the life of me I cant figure out how to make the search results clickable.

If you follow the script you will see that he is using a `div` for the search results (`<div  class="display_box" align="left">`).

I used a hyperlink inside the `<div  class="display_box" align="left">` display and I have managed to work around it, but I can't do it properly with the `.click(function () {`.

I can't catch the events for any tag inside the `<div  class="display_box" align="left"> </div>`

Comment: how did you attach events for anchor tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's probably because the links are added to the dom after the click handler is attached. you could use the jquery `on` method, eg:

```
$('.display_box').on('click', 'a', function(){
  // your code here
});
```

this example assumes that the links are children of the `display_box`

Comment: It also assumes you're using jQuery v1.7+ - otherwise use `delegate()`